# Poor text quality using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: php, text, wkhtmltopdf

I am generating PDF with WKHTMLTOPDF library in PHP project (https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf)

When I generate invoices(PDF) on my local comnputer it is in good quality
[image]

but when I generate it on production server, it gives me this quality
[image]

The options are same (it is same project with same conf). What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: You need to install fonts on your production server. Install `urw-fonts`

Comment: its also subtracted 100005!

Comment: @DevDonkey You made my day. Thanks!

Comment: @Farkie Ok. I will try to install it.

Comment: Did it work? I should have submitted it as an answer really

Comment: @Farkie So the problem really were fonts on server. I had to install Microsoft font. Complete solution is in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete solution is to install Microsoft fonts on server.

1. aptitude install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
2. fc-cache -fv
3. dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig-config (native, automatic, no)
4. dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig
5. restart php-fpm